# SQL - Large XML file maxes out TEMPDB when importing

Tags: sql, xml, cross-apply

I have a query that works just fine for bringing XML data into a SQL table (usually).  My current issue is that I have tried to use this query with a much larger XML file and it maxes out my tempdb (and diskspace) and fails.  Can anyone help?

```
    ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.adc.ca/ETS/v3')
    INSERT INTO [CC-DB].[dbo].[TourTimeLogs] ([Rig],[Job],[Date],[Sheet],[Rev],[TourID],[StartTime],[EndTime],[Mins],[Code],[Detail])
    SELECT 
        RIG = XC.value('(../../../../../../Rig/RigId)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
        JOB = XC.value('(../../../../../../JobNo)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
        DATE = XC.value('(../../../../Date)[1]', 'date'),
        SHEET = XC.value('(../../../../SheetNo)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
        REV = XC.value('(../../../../Revision)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
        TOURID = XC.value('(../../@tourId)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
        STARTTIME = XC.value('(FromTime)[1]', 'datetime'),  
        ENDTIME = XC.value('(ToTime)[1]', 'datetime'),
        MINS = datediff(minute, XC.value('(FromTime)[1]', 'datetime'), XC.value('(ToTime)[1]', 'datetime')),
        TIMECODE = XC.value('(TimeCodeNo)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
        DETAIL = XC.value('(Detail)[1]', 'varchar(100)')    
    FROM 
         [CC-DB].[dbo].[XmlSourceTable] SRC
    CROSS APPLY
        SRC.XmlData.nodes('/ETS/WellTours/WellTour/DayTours/DayTour/Tours/Tour/TimeLogs/TimeLog') AS XT(XC)
```

Comment: The size of tempdb is adjustable and the location of the datafile for tempdb can be set as well. So you can move tempdb to a disk with enough space.

Comment: Our network disk space is limited, the last time I tried this with a huge file - tempdb went up to 20GB and query failed.

Comment: How about reading the XML file in smaller parts and moving it to database. This can be done by a simple .NET page.

Comment: That sounds outside my skillset, was hoping to accomplish this from within this query....

Comment: What is *much larger*? One thing for sure: Your query can be accomplished much more *straight forward*. At the moment you are using one single call to `.nodes()` and then find the *higher* elements with a chain of *back-jumps*. This is expensive, at least in time, but (don't know this) maybe in space also... Please provide a (reduced) example of your XML. Might be, that a different approach of reading solves your issue...

Comment: Works fine with 1MB XML file, I was trying to bring in an 80MB XML file.  Almost impossible to include sample here because to get one full level 1 node is over 20 pages (and has some confidentiality issues as well).

Comment: Hi, one tiny hint: I found this by chance... Without a `@Shnugo` in the comment there's no alert... Well, 80MB is big but not huge... Without the actual structure I cannot help you out, but I'll try an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the actual XML this is reading the *magic glass bulb*, but I'll give it a try:

Your call to

```
.nodes('/ETS/WellTours/WellTour/DayTours/DayTour/Tours/Tour/TimeLogs/TimeLog')
```

tells me, that there is one XML with a root node *ETS* and a nested *1:n-structure* of *WellTours*, *DayTours*, *Tours* and *TimeLogs*.

You might try something like this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.adc.ca/ETS/v3')
INSERT INTO [CC-DB].[dbo].[TourTimeLogs] ([Rig],[Job],[Date],[Sheet],[Rev],[TourID],[StartTime],[EndTime],[Mins],[Code],[Detail])
SELECT 
    RIG = WT.value('(Rig/RigId)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    JOB = WT.value('(JobNo)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    [DATE] = DT.value('(Date)[1]', 'date'),
    SHEET = DT.value('(SheetNo)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    REV = DT.value('(Revision)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    TOURID = T.value('@tourId', 'varchar(100)'),
    STARTTIME = TL.value('(FromTime)[1]', 'datetime'),  
    ENDTIME = TL.value('(ToTime)[1]', 'datetime'),
    MINS = datediff(minute, TL.value('(FromTime)[1]', 'datetime'), TL.value('(ToTime)[1]', 'datetime')),
    TIMECODE = TL.value('(TimeCodeNo)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    DETAIL = TL.value('(Detail)[1]', 'varchar(100)')    
FROM 
     [CC-DB].[dbo].[XmlSourceTable] SRC
CROSS APPLY
    SRC.XmlData.nodes('/ETS/WellTours/WellTour') AS A(WT)
CROSS APPLY
    WT.nodes('DayTours/DayTour') AS B(DT)
CROSS APPLY
    DT.nodes('Tours/Tour') AS C(T)
CROSS APPLY
    T.nodes('TimeLogs/TimeLog') AS D(TL)
```

**attention** If there is nothing returned, try the same with `OUTER APPLY`. Without a real XML to test this, it is a *blind flight* ...

Read as such:

- Find all `<WellTour>`-elements
- Find all `<DayTour>`-elements below each `<WellTour>`
- Find all `<Tour>`-elements below each `<DayTour>`
- Find all `<TimeLog>`-elements below each `<Tour>`

Read the data from the actual level. Do not jump backwards. XML is best to be read *forward-only* (if possible).

Comment: Adding CROSS APPLY statements worked perfectly, just needed to point each of them all back to the root.  Dropped my test file from 47 minutes to 12.  Thanks.

Comment: @C-COOP, glad to read this! What do you mean by *just needed to point each of them all back to the root*? Exactly this should **not** be necessary...

Comment: @C-COOP Without knowing your XML I cannot help you... But - for sure! - this is wrong... One thing is, that you do not keep the connection between a node and its sub-nodes which could lead to wrong data... And - with correct `APPLY`s, this should be much faster... If possible please poste a reduced XML, some nodes of it, to show the principles...

Comment: @C-COOP, greate that you found a solution for this! Still I'd like to see the structure of the actual XML 'cause I'm quite sure, that this can be done still much faster and cleaner than with `CROSS APPLY`s all down from the root...

Comment: OK - thanks....  here it is:  http://www.caodc.ca/sites/default/files/ets/examples/ETS_v3_3_example.xml

Comment: @C-COOP My magic glass bulb works OK, the query is alrigth. But your example has `http://www.adc.ca/ETS/v3` as default namespace, while your linked XML has there `http://www.caodc.ca/ETS/v3`. Try my query with the correct namespace and I would be surprised if this wasn't much faster...

Comment: Yes, was my fault - it did work and you were completely correct - thank you!

Comment: @C-COOP yeah! Just for curiosity: Is there an effect to the size of the tempdb? I'd assume, that this works much less greedy...

Comment: Ha - yes, way faster and barely touches tempdb.